# Django : Unable to login in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have extended the AbstractUser model. But I'm not able to login into the Django admin portal even after creating a superuser. I have even checked the status of `is_staff=True`, `is_superuser=True` & `is_active=True`. All the statuses are true but still not able to log in.

Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    """This Class is used to extend the in-build user model """
    ROLE_CHOICES = (('CREATOR','CREATOR'),('MODERATOR','MODERATOR'),('USERS','USERS'))
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('MALE','MALE'),('FEMALE',"FEMALE"),('OTHER','OTHER'))
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of Birth', null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile_images', verbose_name='Profile Image', default='media/profile_images/default.webp', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(verbose_name='Bio')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Role', choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name='Gender', choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        """ This method is used to modify the password field
        converting text into hashed key"""
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have used the save method because whenever I update a user the password is used to get stored in plain text.

Comment: Your save method is causing issues, remove it. Every time a User is saved the previous hash is being hashed again and then you won't be able to use the previous password. The UserManager has the methods for creating users and reseting passwords

Comment: Thanks @Iain Shelvington it worked. Thanks alot

Comment: But can u please tell me how can I hash the password while updating the user model.

Comment: `def create(self, validated_data):
  logger.info('Information Incoming!')
  return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

 def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
  user = super().update( *args, **kwargs)
  p = user.password
  user.set_password(p)
  user.save()
  return user '